# Package officer does not write flextable to word when flextable function delete_rows is used

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I am using most up to date version of packages (flextable 0.9.4 and officer 0.6.3). It exports table perfectly when delete_rows function is not used and gives this error message when it is used: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "vertical.align", value = c("center",  : replacement has 132 rows, data has 102

Is there any way to fix this?

I tried to run it with and without delete_rows function.

Comment: this is a bug. Thanks for letting us now, we are able to reproduce it and will fix it soon